# .NET File.Delete -- How to flush filesystem changes?

Tags: .net, filesystems, flush

Here's the screwed up situation: I've got a SD card attached to a SATA interface via a SD-to-SATA hardware controller. So, Windows thinks it's a SATA device. But really, it's not. So this has some screwy side-effects.

I'm trying to delete some files from the SD card, using File.Delete from the .NET Framework. This works without error, and the files are in fact deleted and cannot be accessed from the host machine anymore.

BUT -- when I remove the SD card with the machine running, then put the SD card into another machine, the deleted files are still there in all their glory.

So, apparently the host machine has made file system changes in cache somewhere and not flushed them to disk, and they are never getting applied.

Is there any way I can force the host machine to update the filesystem tables on the disk, i.e., to flush them out?

Thanks.